# WordPress Multisite Subsite WP admin not woring

Tags: wordpress, multisite, domain-mapping

I used the MU Domain Mapping plugin to map the domains, Currently, I am not able to login into other subsites which are pointed to other domains.

It is showing me the error.

The domain mapping plugin only works if the site is installed in /. This is a limitation of how virtual servers work and is very difficult to work around.

I used the below settings in wp-config file.

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydomainname');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' ); 

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '');
//define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Please help me.